# Increase vertical spacing in multiple choice questions

Tags: pdftex

I use the ex_test package to compose multiple choice questions. In sentences with fractions, or integrals, the distance between the question and the answer is small, and the vertical distance between the answers is also small. How to increase them, I don't want to use \vspace because there are many such questions.
https://www.overleaf.com/4161167633ndxfhycbdmtj
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't find any documentation for this package (that is not published as far as I can say?), but based on the source code you provide, I found that `\parskipchoice` seems to control the space between items, and the macro `\picinpar` seems to be inserted before all code instructions (I can't find any better variable for this, but I might have missed it). This means that you can do something like that:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\picinpar}{\vspace{3mm}}{}{}
\def\parskipchoice{3mm}
```

(a cleaner solution might exists, but the lack of documentation does not help… I tried to see if `\setlistsEX` could help, but it seems to control something else)

PS: next time, try to put all the code in this question. It might help people to search for it, it's easier to copy/paste/test, and there is no risk to see it deleted in the future.

**Full MWE (needs the .sty file included in the OP question to work)**

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}   
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,mathrsfs,esvect}
\usepackage[top=1.2cm, bottom=2.2cm, left=1.5cm, right=1.5cm] {geometry}

\usepackage[dethi]{ex_test}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\picinpar}{\vspace{3mm}}{}{}
\def\parskipchoice{3mm}

\begin{document}
\Opensolutionfile{ans}
\begin{ex}%[2D4Y1-1]
    Tìm mô-đun của số phức $z=-3+4i$.
    \choice
    {$1$}
    {\True $5$}
    {$25$}
    {$7$}
\end{ex}
\begin{ex}%[2H3Y3-4]
    Trong không gian $Oxyz$, đường thẳng đi qua điểm $M(1; 2; -3)$ và nhận véc-tơ $\vv{u}=(2; -1; 1)$ làm véc-tơ chỉ phương có phương trình chính tắc là
        \choice
    {\True $\dfrac{x-1}{2}=\dfrac{y-2}{-1}=\dfrac{z+3}{1}$}
    {$\dfrac{x+2}{1}=\dfrac{y-1}{2}=\dfrac{z+1}{-3}$}
    {$\dfrac{x-2}{1}=\dfrac{y+1}{2}=\dfrac{z-1}{-3}$}
    {$\dfrac{x+1}{2}=\dfrac{y-2}{-1}=\dfrac{z-3}{1}$}
\end{ex}

\begin{ex}%[2D3Y1-3]
    Cho hàm số $f(x)=\mathrm{e}^{3x}$. Trong các khẳng định sau khẳng định nào \textbf{đúng}?
    \choice
    {\True $\displaystyle \int\limits f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\dfrac{1}{3}\mathrm{e}^{3x}+C$}
    {$\displaystyle \int\limits f(x) \mathrm{d}x=3\mathrm{e}^{3x}+C$}
    {$\displaystyle \int\limits f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\mathrm{e}^{3x}+C$}
    {$\displaystyle \int\limits f(x) \mathrm{d}x=-\mathrm{e}^{3x}+C$}
\end{ex}
\Closesolutionfile{ans}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The ex_test package does not have an English manual. Because of my little knowledge, I cannot include it in the same document. I tried your way, this is what I needed. Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Then if your problem is solved, make sure to accept the solution by clicking on the tick mark to let other people know it's solved ;-)